# Mongodb performance issue with simple search query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

This is a sample structure of a collection i am having in mongodb, likewise some 60+ lakh similar records are there in one collection. We moved to mongodb seeing the fast accessing performance,but now its bit hard to say evean simple searching is taking huge time. I have given index for the search params. For name searching (search params MNG_FIRST_NAME, MNG_MIDDLE_NAME, MNG_LAST_NAME, MNG_ALIASIST.AKAFIRST_NAME, MNG_ALIASIST.AKALAST_NAME).
Please consider is the method i'm following the correct way with mongodb.

**Please find the code sample and collection structure below i'm using.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5308e2e1f525bc0f0472cbf6"),
    "MNG_UID" : "1389120",
    "MNG_CATEGORY" : "OFFICER",
    "MNG_FIRST_NAME" : "JOHN",
    "MNG_LAST_NAME" : "DOE",
    "MNG_MIDDLE_NAME" : "MARK",
    "MNG_CREATEDON" : "2010-11-19",
    "MNG_UPDATEDON" : "2014-01-01",
    "MNG_TITLE" : "Dr",
    "MNG_REMARKS" : "",
    "MNG_TYPE" : "WORLDCHECK",
    "MNG_PROGRAMLIST" : [],
    "MNG_IDLIST" : [],
    "MNG_ALIASIST" : [ 
        {
            "AKAUID" : "101",
            "AKATYPE" : "ALIAS",
            "AKACATEGORY" : "",
            "AKAFIRST_NAME" : "JOHNNY TURA, DOE",
            "AKALAST_NAME" : ""
        },
        {
            "AKAUID" : "102",
            "AKATYPE" : "ALIAS",
            "AKACATEGORY" : "",
            "AKAFIRST_NAME" : "MARK TURA, DOE",
            "AKALAST_NAME" : ""
        }
    ],
    "MNG_ADDRESSLIST" : [ 
        {
            "ADDRESSUID" : "",
            "ADDRESS1" : "Dakar",
            "ADDRESS2" : "Dakar",
            "ADDRESS3" : "SENEGAL",
            "ADDRESSCITY" : "Dakar",
            "ADDRESSCOUNTRY" : "SENEGAL",
            "ADDRESSPOCODE" : "",
            "ADDRESSSTATE" : "Dakar"
        }
    ],
    "MNG_NATIONALITYLIST" : [ 
        {
            "NATUID" : "",
            "NATCOUNTRY" : "ISRAEL",
            "NATMAINENTRY" : ""
        },
    {
            "NATUID" : "",
            "NATCOUNTRY" : "AMERICIAN",
            "NATMAINENTRY" : ""
        }
    ],
    "MNG_CITIZENSHIPLIST" : [],
    "MNG_DOBLIST" : [],
    "MNG_PLACEOBLIST" : [],
    "MNG_ADDINFOLIST" : []
}
```

**code used to obtain collection using mongodb c# driver**

```
    string MNG_REMTNAME = "JOHN";

    var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<EMPLOYEES>("EMPLOYEES");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MNG_REMTNAME))
    {
       IMongoQuery MFName = new QueryDocument();
       MFName = Query.Or(Query.Matches("MNG_FIRST_NAME", MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper()),
                Query.Matches("MNG_MIDDLE_NAME", MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper()),
                Query.Matches("MNG_LAST_NAME", MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper()),
                Query.ElemMatch("MNG_ALIASIST", Query.Or(Query.Matches("AKAFIRST_NAME",
MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper())))
                );
    }
    var colln = collection.Find(MFName).ToList();
```

Please help with some solution to increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
Query.ElemMatch("MNG_ALIASIST", Query.Or(Query.Matches("AKAFIRST_NAME",
MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper())))
```

for this one

```
Query.ElemMatch("MNG_ALIASIST", Query.EQ("AKAFIRST_NAME", MNG_REMTNAME.ToUpper()))
```

Also have in mind that searching in MongoDB Arrays is very expensive unless you have the proper Indexes. So make sure that you have an index with at least the field `MNG_ALIASIST`.

Consider creating a Multikey index for this field http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/

Comment: i have corrected the code sample..i'm searching the name in the array MNG_ALIASIST - AKAFIRST_NAME, AKALAST_NAME. i have given index for these params too.

Comment: i used Query.Or because i'm searching criteria in both AKAFIRST_NAME and AKALAST_NAME. i will try to add multikey index and check the performance